# GWT Convert ClickHandler to MouseDownHandler

Tags: gwt, onclick, onmousedown

A solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29079118/2442991) seems to be to use onMouseDown instead of onClick.

To avoid changing all the buttons throughout the application, I wanted to change the Button widget's addClickHandler so that it adds a MouseDownHandler instead.

Something like

```
@Override
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler clickHandler) {
    return button.addMouseDownHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
        clickHandler.onClick(event);

    }
  });
}
```

But I cannot pass a MouseDownEvent to the ClickHandler and I cannot instantiate a ClickEvent.

What's the best way to go?